# Configure PDF page width using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to generate a pdf using puppeteer but the pdf generated is of large width. I want to have pdf which shows all content in one page and must be of width 4.8cm where page height can be of any length its content has.

I added configuration to pdf

```
{
  path            : filePath,
  printBackground : true,
  width           : '4.8cm'
}
```

And To page I added configuration to viewport

```
{
  width             : 136,
  height            : 842,
  deviceScaleFactor : 1
}
```

But the end result is not changing

Comment: You should give width in pixels.

Comment: pixel is default for viewport @PrabhjotSinghKainth

Comment: I meant pdf page width , where you have used 4.8 cm

Comment: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pageframes docs says its valid too

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I tried chnging to pixels but still the same

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, and select this answer as correct, if it works perfectly.

I set the scale options inside the `page.pdf` method to scale the original printed PDF to the scaled version. So this make the full page fit in one page only.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const pageURL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59464250/configure-pdf-page-width-using-puppeteer'

const optionsPDF = {
    path: 'print.pdf',
    printBackground: true,
    width: '4.8cm',
    scale: 1,
    preferCSSPageSize: false
}

;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        devtools: false,
        defaultViewport: {
            width             : 136,
            height            : 842,
            deviceScaleFactor : 1
        }
    })
    const [page] = await browser.pages()
    await page.emulateMedia('screen')

    await page.goto( pageURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 })

    const height_weight_ratio = await page.evaluate( () => window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth)
    const height = parseInt(optionsPDF.width) * height_weight_ratio
    optionsPDF.scale = 1/height_weight_ratio

    console.log('Printing PDF...')
    await page.pdf(optionsPDF)

    await browser.close()

})()
```

Comment: I'm assuming height is supposed to be added to the PDF object and have "cm" appended?